# How to improve the runtime of this matrix generation loop in python3?

Tags: python, arrays, loops, numerical-computing

I have code that is simulating interactions between lots of particles. Using profiling, I've worked out that the function that's causing the most slowdown is a loop which iterates over all my particles and works out the time for the collision between each of them. This generates a symmetric matrix, which I then take the minimum value out of.

```
def find_next_collision(self, print_matrix = False):
    """
    Sets up a matrix of collision times
    Returns the indices of the balls in self.list_of_balls that are due to
    collide next and the time to the next collision
    """
    self.coll_time_matrix = np.zeros((np.size(self.list_of_balls), np.size(self.list_of_balls)))

    for i in range(np.size(self.list_of_balls)):
        for j in range(i+1):
            if (j==i):
                self.coll_time_matrix[i][j] = np.inf
            else:
                self.coll_time_matrix[i][j] = self.list_of_balls[i].time_to_collision(self.list_of_balls[j])
    matrix = self.coll_time_matrix + self.coll_time_matrix.T
    self.coll_time_matrix = matrix
    ind = np.unravel_index(np.argmin(self.coll_time_matrix, axis = None), self.coll_time_matrix.shape)
    dt = self.coll_time_matrix[ind]
    if (print_matrix):
        print(self.coll_time_matrix)
    return dt, ind
```

This code is a method inside a class which defines the positions of all of the particles. Each of these particles is an object saved in `self.list_of_balls` (which is a list). As you can see, I'm already only iterating over half of this matrix, but it's still quite a slow function. I've tried using numba, but this is a section of quite a large code, and I don't want to have to optimize every function with numba when this is the slow one.

Does anyone have any ideas for a more efficient way to write this function?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Like [Raubsauger mentioned in their answer](/a/63723313/843953), evaluating `if`s is slow

```
for j in range(i+1): 
    if (j==i):
```

You can get rid of this `if` by simply doing `for j in range(i)`. That way `j` goes from `0` to `i-1`

You should also try to avoid loops when possible. You can do this by expressing your problem in a vectorized way, and using numpy or scipy functions that [leverage SIMD operations](/q/44944367/843953) to speed up calculations. Here's a simplified example assuming the `time_to_collision` simply divides Euclidean distance by speed. If you store the coordinates and speeds of the balls in a numpy array instead of storing ball objects in a list, you could do:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist
rel_distances = pdist(ball_coordinates)
rel_speeds = pdist(ball_speeds)
time = rel_distances / rel_speeds
```

[pdist documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.pdist)

Of course, this isn't going to work verbatim if your `time_to_collision` function is more complicated, but it should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

First Question: How many particles do you have?

If you have a lot of particles: one improvement would be

```
    for i in range(np.size(self.list_of_balls)):
        for j in range(i):
            self.coll_time_matrix[i][j] = self.list_of_balls[i].time_to_collision(self.list_of_balls[j])
        self.coll_time_matrix[i][i] = np.inf
```

often executed `if`s slow everything down. Avoid them in innerloops

2nd question: is it necessary to compute this every time? Wouldn't it be faster to compute points in time and only refresh those lines and columns which were involved in a collision?

Edit:

Idea here is to initially calculate either the time left or (better solution) the timestamp for the collision as you already as well as the order. But instead to throw the calculated results away, you only update the values when needed. This way you need to calculate only 2*n instead of n^2/2 values.

Sketch:

```
# init step, done once at the beginning, might need an own function
matrix ... # calculate matrix like before; I asume that you use timestamps instead of time left
min_times = np.zeros(np.size(self.list_of_balls))
for i in range(np.size(self.list_of_balls)):
    min_times[i] = min(self.coll_time_matrix[i])
order_coll = np.argsort(min_times)

ind = order_coll[0]
dt = self.coll_time_matrix[ind]
return dt, ind


# function step: if a collision happened, order_coll[0] and order_coll[1] hit each other

for balls in order_coll[0:2]:
    for i in range(np.size(self.list_of_balls)):
        self.coll_time_matrix[balls][i] = self.list_of_balls[balls].time_to_collision(self.list_of_balls[i])
        self.coll_time_matrix[i][balls] = self.coll_time_matrix[balls][i]
    self.coll_time_matrix[balls][balls] = np.inf
for i in range(np.size(self.list_of_balls)):
    min_times[i] = min(self.coll_time_matrix[i])
order_coll = np.argsort(min_times)

ind = order_coll[0]
dt = self.coll_time_matrix[ind]
return dt, ind
```

In case you calculate time left in the matrix you have to subtract the time passed from the matrix. Also you somehow need to store the matrix and (optionally) min_times and order_coll.

Comment: Thanks for your help. There are ~1000 particles. And sadly it is, I only carry out the collision of two particles in each step, but I need to work out the time it would take for every particle to collide in order to work out which are the two that need to collide

Comment: _"often executed ifs slow everything down. Avoid them in innerloops"_ Context is important though. If your `time_to_collision` function takes ages to run, it makes no sense running it when `i == j` and then discarding those values because using an `if` would be faster.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I've implemented it and it leads to a speed up of ~3 times for 100 particles. The if statement change doesn't affect much, I think because as Pranav points out, time_to_collision is slower

Comment: I'm interested in the speedup for 1000 particles :)